# Link value of links from social media

Tags: seo, links, social-media, value

As a SEO you can benefit from Social Media activities and it even seems key according to [Matt Cutts recent video on SEO in 2011](http://www.goboozo.com/2011/03/matt-cutts-on-seo-in-2011/). However besides getting 'inbound links' from third party websites or blogs as a result of people that have noticed e.g. your Twitter Tweet or Facebook Post you will, most likely, also receive links from the social media pages itself.

**Now, when talking about 'link-value' would Googlebot consider a link from a Social Media page the same value as a link from a website or blog?**

Please note: It goes without saying that I understand that the page must be publicly visible, not restricted by e.g. htaccess, should be lacking no-follow tags and that in case an url is shortened it should be done by applying the appropriate redirect. The question is solely about the valuation of a link published on a social media platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between a page on a social media platform and on a non-social media platform (a regular page). Google considers them the same type of thing. But it is what is on those pages that will make the difference. For instance:

- Sites like Twitter that have pages with lots of links will give each link less value than pages with just a few links. A webpage that also contains a large list of links will also give less link juice.
- Social Media Sites usually have a lot of text that lowers the keyword density of the page making the page seem less relevant to your link (lower link juice). An article for example will have good keyword density and your link will have more relevancy.
- Lots of Social Media sites use No follow links which will affect link juice as well. A blog with no follow links will give the same result.

So on average, a social media page compared to a relevant regular webpage will give you less link juice for having a link on there, link for link. But it is still a good thing to do. Compare the number of links you may have scattered around social media sites compared to on regular webpages.

So in summary, evaluate a social media page just like you would any webpage.

Comment: Keyword Density? Didn't that mythical term die already? I'm *sure* you meant keyword frequency and/or relevance.

Comment: As of 2013, Twitter, Facbook and Pinterest all use nofollow for external links: https://blog.thatagency.com/design-studio-blog/2013/09/social-media-backlinks-dofollow-or-nofollow/

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a link from a social media website as far as Google is concerned. The page, not the website, is either relevant to your search term or not. It doesn't matter if it's on a blog, forum, article, social platform, or whatever else you can think of. Just being on a social site, or any other site, means nothing. It's the quality and relevance of the page the links are on that matters.

Comment: Actually I didn't mean a link from a social media to Google, but from a social media to the website I am trying to promote / my own website.

Comment: I know. That's how I answered the question. I'll reword it so it;s clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly there is no "keyword density" it is a old myth. 
There is no difference between pages only difference between links types.
anchor text links or links from graphical element with alt text, do-follow or on-follow .....ect