# Are links from authoritative social media pages more valuable for SEO?

Tags: seo, backlinks

In the context of SEO, is there any evidence that link juice (from backlinks) on social media pages (FB, Twitter, etc) is dependent upon some kind of quality index of the social media page?

I.e, does a share on a university's social media page carry any more weight than a share from someone's personal social media page?  We know that backlinks from .edu web pages carry more weight, but what about their social media pages?

I've read [Link value of links from social media](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11165/link-value-of-links-from-social-media) and John Conde's answer there, but John is focused on the content of the page.  I'm thinking of the entity behind the page.

Comment: The "nofollow" part of the accepted answer on [Link value of links from social media](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11165/link-value-of-links-from-social-media) is more relevant.   Facebook, Twitter, and Pinterest all use nofollow, so there is little hope of getting any link juice via social media, regardless of entity behind the social media page.